# Need to delete all data after third colon of a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i have a file say test.txt with the following contents

```
apple:orange:mango:123:1234:12345
```

i want all data after third colon to be removed

Expected output

```
apple:orange:mango:
```

Kinldy help

Comment: This site is not a coding service.  At least show what you have tried.

Comment: Use `awk -F":" '{print $1":"$2":"$3":"}'`

Comment: Or even `awk 'NF=3' FS=: OFS=:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backreference:

```
sed 's/\([^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:\).*/\1/' test.txt
```

or with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(([^:]*:){3}).*/\1/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

using `grep`: IF last colon is required.

```
grep -oP '^.*?:.*?:.*?:' input
apple:orange:mango:
```

If last colon is not required:

```
grep -oP '^.*?:.*?:[^:]+' input
apple:orange:mango
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `cut`, for example `cut -d: -f1-3 test.txt`. It show first, second and third columns. If you need other range of columns just replace `-f1-3` with what you need.

`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo apple:orange:mango:123:1234:12345| awk '{gsub(/[0-9]:*/,"")}1'
apple:orange:mango:
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.